# How can I mimic glutinous rice inexpensively in Latin America?

Tags: substitutions, rice

I know that certain rice should be bought for cooking meals like sushi (glutinous rice which is almost 5 dollars per kilogram). In Latin America the most common rice is about 1 dollar per kilogram.

Is there a possible way to get the same sticky effect with regular rice instead of glutinous "expensive" rice?

Answer (score 3):

Sushi rice is not the same as "sweet" or "glutinous" rice.  Sushi rice is simply a short grain rice.  It is seasoned, after cooking, with a sugar/salt/rice wine mixture that helps flavor it and hold it together when used for making sushi.  If that is your goal, you could probably come close  by experimenting with other short grained rices.

"Sweet", "glutinous", or "sticky rice" is soaked then steamed.  It sticks together naturally, and is often eaten with the hands in small clumps.

So, I guess the more important question is what is your goal?

Comment: Hello, thanks for telling me some hint.. my goal is to make sushi so i will try as you said with short grain rices :)